# gentic-linkage is misspelled (filler text to please auto-filter)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

The tag [`gentic-linkage`](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/gentic-linkage/info) is misspelled. It should be `genetic-linkage`. How can we fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done. I renamed the misspelt tag with the correct term.